# Pixel Shader from Visual Studio Graphics Diagnostics

Tags: shaders, directx11, hlsl, visual-studio, c++

i want to check my pixel shader variables in graphics diagnostics but unfortunately when i click start debugging in pixel history (mentioned below), a new tap will open and says source is not available. am i have to do anything before start debugging my shader in graphics diagnostics tool ?

Thanks

[image]
[image]

just to mention that, I use DirectX 11 and C++

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason was because of my .fx shader instead of .hlsl files.